# The set of all possible values of $AC$ is an open interval $(m,n)$

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, interval-arithmetic

> Side $\overline{AB}$ of $\triangle ABC$ has length $10$. The bisector of angle $A$ meets $\overline{BC}$ at $D$, and $CD = 3$. The set of all possible values of $AC$ is an open interval $(m,n)$. What is $m+n$?
>
> A) 16 B) 17 C) 18 D) 19 E) 20

Could someone help me understand what is wrong with my approach (none of the answers matches mine!):

Letting BD equal $x$ (which must be positive) and using the angle bisector theorem, we get that AC is $\frac{30}{x}$. Using triangular inequality, we get that $$7 < x+\frac{30}{x}$$ $$x<7+\frac{30}{x}$$ and $$\frac{30}{x} < 13+x.$$

We can multiply $x$ to both sides of all 3 inequalities because $x>0$ and will not change the direction of the inequality. Doing so and moving all terms to the LHS, we get $x^2-77x+30>0$ (1), $x^2-7x-30<0$ (2) and $x^2+13x-30>0$ (3). (1) is always true because we can re-write it in the form of $(x-a)^2+b>0$ where $a$ and $b$ are both positive. (2) can be rewritten as $(x+3)(x-10)<0$, and thus $-3<x<10$. But $x>0$, so $0<x<10$.

Finally, (3) can also be written as $(x+15)(x-2)>0$ where only $x>2$ works because $x<-15$ is less than 0. Then combining all the scenarios, $x$ can range from $2$ to $10$, but $12$ is not an option... I've double/triple checked my work, but there must be something I'm missing.

Comment: This is a minor point, but there is a typo in your $\left(1\right)$ equation, where $- 77x$ should be $-7x$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan — ah, right. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have the correct range for $x$ of $2 \lt x \lt 10$, but that is for $\overline{BD}$. However, the question asks for $\overline{AC}$. Since $\overline{AC} = \frac{30}{x}$, this means it's range is $3 \lt \overline{AC} \lt 15$, so $m = 3$ and $n = 15$, giving the correct answer of $m + n = 3 + 15 = 18$, i.e., choice $C$.

Comment: Okay, I see this was a pretty careless mistake now... Perhaps I should have set AC into $x$ instead.

Comment: @jjhh Perhaps it would have been better to have $\overline{AC} = x$ instead, with $\overline{BD} = \frac{30}{x}$ in that case. IMO, it's usually not too important which values you set to be specific variables, as long as you keep track of what you're trying to determine. However, although it doesn't make too much difference here, in some more complicated problems, using the appropriate variables can help make the calculations much easier & simpler than they could be otherwise.